# Creating a vertical thumbnail with 3 images on display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I need help on creating a vertical thumbnail with three images on display with prev. and next buttons to display the other images. These images are looped from a database. The image below is a preview of what I would like to have. Like for example I have 5 images, my page should display 1st 2nd and 3rd images. Then by clicking next button it should hide 1st image and display only 2nd, 3rd, and 4th images. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

so far, this is what i've accomplished.

[image]

I just hide the extra images using css "overflow:hidden". I don't know how to add previous and next buttons to bring them up.

This is some of my codes:

```
            {foreach from=$images item=i name=images}
            {if $smarty.foreach.images.iteration <= 16 }
              <div class="thumbnail col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="{$i.image_url|amp}" thumb="{$i.image_url|amp}" data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="fancybox" {if $smarty.foreach.images.iteration eq 1} id="first_icon"{/if} onclick="return {if $config.Detailed_Product_Images.is_jqzoom eq 'Y'}false{else}dicon_click({$smarty.foreach.images.iteration}, '{$config.Detailed_Product_Images.det_slideshow_delay}', '{$images_counter}');{/if}" {if $config.Detailed_Product_Images.is_rollover eq 'Y'} onmouseover="func_mouse_over(this, {$i.thbn_image_x}, {$i.thbn_image_y});"{/if}  target="_blank">
            <img src="{$i.image_url|amp}" alt="" >
              </a></div>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

This part is for displaying the thumbnail only. Don't mind the href portion.

Comment: use jquery, change <something> on click/change event, <something> can be whole image child element, attribute such as src/background-image ... should add some code so other users can suggest edits. if you do not know how to do it at all, search for prepared recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated answer. It's a little tricky since you have to fiddle with the DOM to get the images to scroll around in a carousel fashion. What this does is gets the thumbnail images and shows the first three, while hiding the rest.

Then, each time the next button is clicked, it removes the first image from the DOM and slams it on the end of the list, then shows the first three images while hiding the rest.

So you really don't need an array, but you kinda have the same idea going: take the first thing off, put it on the end, then show the first three and hide the rest.

**EDIT**: I realized we don't need to use JavaScript to show/hide the elements, it's much simpler with CSS. Just remove the first child, append him to the end and let CSS display the first 3 children.

```js
var thumbs = document.querySelector('.thumbs');
var next = document.querySelector('button');

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var child = thumbs.removeChild(thumbs.firstElementChild);
  thumbs.appendChild(child);
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.thumb:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbs">
  <div class="thumb">
    img 1
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    img 2
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    img 3
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    img 4
  </div>
  <div class="thumb">
    img 5
  </div>
</div>
<button>
  Next
</button>
```

Here's an example of an image gallery that was used to answer a different question, but you can see the idea with the "Next" button.

https://jsfiddle.net/subterrane/bb196sts/

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var ix = 0; ix < images.length; ix++) {
     images[ix].style.display = 'none';
    }

     index++;
     if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    images[index].style.display = 'block';
});
```

You add an event handler to your button(s) and show/hide the images appropriately.

Comment: tnx for the reply. I need to display 3 images by default. like for example, i have 5 images, my page should display the first 3 images and hide the rest of images and by clicking next button it will hide 1st image and display 2nd, 3rd, and 4th image.

Comment: So you need to place references to your image elements in a list of 5 and only display the first three images. Then when they click the next button, you take an image off the front and put it on the back of the list, hide all of the images, then display the first three. Does this sound like something Javascript can do? Maybe with an array? Perhaps with a `shift` and a `push` method?

Comment: yes. but I'm not that good in javascript/jquery that's why I'm having a hard time for this one.

Comment: tnx again for the response. I'm gonna study your code and try to integrate it. cheers.

Comment: Hi Will, I successfully integrated your codes into my page. thank you so much. By the way if your not busy, do you mind helping me setup a previous button too.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a code-writing service but I can help you try to figure it out. I recently answered a question not unlike the one you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963412/getting-next-and-previous-element-of-json-array Give it a read and see what you can come up with and we'll go from there.

Comment: Tnx for your example Will. I've tried looking at it for hours but I couldnt figure it out to work with what I have base on your first example. So, I've looked at other sources and this one solved my problem for prev and next button. http://jsfiddle.net/Uttv8/