# Getting next and previous element of json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help with my code. I want to have a previous and a next button, these will call a function viewBlogItem(direction,cat,blogid);

in that function i'll be reading out the json file, categorizing by the "category".

Every blogItem has a articleid and a category, if click the next button I want to have the next blogItem.articleid and have that one shown (I use append for that one). If the direction == "next", then it look if it has a next item in category, if not then hide $('.next'). Same goes for previous button $('.previous')

blogItems.json

```
{
  "blogItem":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "animals blog 1",
      "category":"animals",
      "text":"text",
      "articleid":1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "lifestyle blog 1",
      "category":"lifestyle",
      "text":"text",
      "articleid": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "animals blog 2",
      "category":"animals",
      "text":"text",
      "articleid": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "animals blog 4",
      "category":"dieren",
      "text":"text",
      "articleid":4
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "animals blog 5",
      "category":"animals",
      "text":"text",
      "articleid":3
    }
  ]
}
```

jquery

```
 function viewBlogItem(direction,cat,blogid) {
            var id = "";
            if(direction == "next"){
                // code for showing next blogitem
                //if no next then
                $('').hide();
            }
            else{
                // if no previous then hide
                //code for showing previous blogitem
            }
            loadBlog(id);
        }

    function loadBlog(blogid){
        $.getJSON('blogitems.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data.blogItem, function (i, item) {
                if (item.id == blogid) {
                    $('.view').append('all sorts of stuff');
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I would also like to have some suggestions for the structure my json.

Comment: You probably need to do things the other way around. That is, leave the buttons hidden, load the blog data, THEN decide if the buttons can be shown. You don't have the information until after you fetch your blog data from the server.

Comment: How can I tell that there ain't another blog after or previous?

Comment: You should create the JSON in the way you can use it in Javascript. For each `blogItem` create previous and next properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I tell that there ain't another blog after or previous?

Look at the index of the current blog item and see if the next one is bigger than than the number of items in the array or if the previous one is less than 0.

```js
var blogs = {
    "blogItem": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "animals blog 1",
        "category": "animals",
        "text": "text",
        "articleid": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "lifestyle blog 1",
        "category": "lifestyle",
        "text": "text",
        "articleid": 1
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "animals blog 2",
        "category": "animals",
        "text": "text",
        "articleid": 2
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "animals blog 4",
        "category": "dieren",
        "text": "text",
        "articleid": 4
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "animals blog 5",
        "category": "animals",
        "text": "text",
        "articleid": 3
    }]
};

var index = 0;
var item = blogs.blogItem[index];

var title = document.getElementById('title');
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');
var next = document.getElementById('next');

displayItem(item);

previous.addEventListener('click', function() {
    displayItem(blogs.blogItem[--index]);
});

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    displayItem(blogs.blogItem[++index]);
});

function displayItem(item) {
    title.innerText = item.title;
    text.innerText = item.text;
    previous.disabled = index <= 0;
    next.disabled = index >= blogs.blogItem.length -1;
}
```

```css
[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="text"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `index < blogs.blogItem.length - 1 ? false : true;`, please write `index >= blogs.blogItem.length - 1`

Comment: Thanks so much ! I added a category check in the function! I really really appreciate your comment. I was stuck on this one :) now I can continue!