# Skipping to the next object in a JSON Array and populating an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have built a form that populates the fields with data from an array.

I have 2 buttons, one which will 'post' with Ajax - Submit, and one which I am trying to skip to the next object in the array - Skip.

I can't figure out how to make the skip button work. I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963412/getting-next-and-previous-element-of-json-array) code that lets you skip to the next record, when its only one record displaying, however I have many records I am adding to div's, so need something else.

How do I skip to the next object in the array?

Here is a JSfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8vf4rs1w/

Here is the code a simplified code. I have about 20 input boxes I am adding data too.

```
<form>

<h1>Record: #<div id="record_id"></div></h1><h5>Date Added: <div id="date_added"></div></h5><br/>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="est_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="est_name" placeholder="Est Name" disabled>
      </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verify</button>
    <button type="button" id="skip" class="btn btn-secondary">Skip</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Get Json

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('getJSON.php', { get_param: 'name' }, function (data) {
              console.log(data)

              var index = 0;

              var record_id = data[index].id;
              var est_name = data[index].name;
              var date_added = data[0].reg_date;

              $('#record_id').text(record_id);
              $('#date_added').text(date_added);
              $('#est_name').val($('#est_name').val() + est_name);

        });
    });
```

JSON

```
[ 0: {id: "1", name: "name1", locale: "locale1" }
    1: {id: "2", name: "name2", locale: "locale2" }
    2: {id: "3", name: "name3", locale: "locale3" } ]
```

Comment: Could you also provide a sample of your JSON?

Comment: @rmn Just added a simplified sample! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll through your records array you have to store the array and index in a higher scope and increment the index when the skip button is clicked like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // The variables that need to be remembered throughout the app
    var index = 0;
    var records = [];

    // Function to set form values
    function displayRecord(){
        var record = records[index];
        $('#record_id').text(record.id);
        $('#date_added').text(record.reg_date);
        $('#est_name').val(record.name);
    }

    // Increment index when the skip button is clicked and display data
    document.getElementById('skip').addEventListener('click', function(){
        index++;
        displayRecord();
    });

    $.getJSON(/**/
        records = data;
        displayRecord();   
    /**/);   
});
```

Comment: Not having much luck implementing this! I can see that it's getting the data. Just not going to the next object! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @tbowden I've edited my answer to show an example how you can set the form data at the right moment.

Comment: Works Perfectly!